# Scheduling push notifications with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, cron, push-notification, scheduled-tasks

I have been recently tasked to implement a push notification system for the mobile apps of a commercial web app using Symfony2.

I have used RMSPushNotificationsBundle(https://github.com/richsage/RMSPushNotificationsBundle) for creating and sending the messages and implemented some event-listeners to send some on-the-fly notifications to the clientele list. Due to the fact that we also need to have scheduled notifications, i have created a couple of symfony commands which are executed through cron jobs. The code behind those commands mainly checks for scheduled notifications every 30 minutes and if any notification is to be sent in the current time interval, it sents it.

Currently everything works fine. My main concern regards the scalability of the current implementations as the user-base is expected to grow a lot.

Is there a better way to go regarding the scheduled notifications? I know that this is a bit generic question but i would really appreciate any kind of insight/ advice.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a question of scheduling but of scaling. With GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) you can push to multiple devices at once (up to 1000): https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#target

This will reduce the request overhead. RMSPushNotificationsBundle supports this, too: https://github.com/richsage/RMSPushNotificationsBundle/pull/44